# Linked List not reading file correctly

Tags: java

So basically I have a Linked List class that has all of the constructor data necessary to read a file I have and then convert it into a Linked List. However when it reads in the file data it is adding lines and spaces incorrectly. I am using system.out.println to check and it is coming out incorrectly. I don't think it is the toString method because I have messed with it so much and nothing changes. I need help with this because I cant figure it out.
Thanks!

**File Information(Basically All of the data is on separate lines):**

```
tobi
tobi
tobi@hotmail.com
tobi
Mixed Breed
Male
3-4
Virginia
Walking
lily
lily
lily@hotmail.com
lily
Yorkshire Terrier
Female
3-4
Hawaii
Jumping
peppy
peppy
peppy@hotmail.com
peppy
Chihuahua
Male
7-8
Alaska
Sleeping
fluffy
fluffy
fluffy@hotmail.com
fluffy
MixedBreed
Female
3-4
Virginia
Walking 
flower
flower
flower@hotmail.com
flower
Chihuahua
Female
7-8
Alaska
Sleeping
```

**Linked List:**

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.*;

    public class LinkedAccountList implements Serializable{

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private String state;
    private String hobby;

    public LinkedAccountList (String username, String password, String email, String name, String breed, String gender, String age, String state, String hobby){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.state = state;
    this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
    return username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
    return password;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
    return email;
    }

    public String getName(){
    return name;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
    return breed;
    }

    public String getGender(){
    return gender;
    }

    public String getAge(){
    return age;
    }

    public String getState(){
    return state;
    }

    public String getHobby(){
    return hobby;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Username: "+username+"\nPassword: "+password+"\nEmail: "+email+"\nName: "+name+"\nBreed: "+breed+"\nGender: "+gender+"\nAge: "+age+"\nState: "+state+"\nHobby: "+hobby;
    }

    public void setUsername(String u){
    username = u;
    }

    public void setPassword(String p){
    password = p;
    }

    public void setEmail(String e){
    email = e;
    }

    public void setName(String n){
    name = n;
    }

    public void setBreed(String b){
    breed = b;
    }

    public void setGender(String g){
    gender = g;
    }

    public void setAge(String a){
    age = a;
    }

    public void setState(String s){
    state = s;
    }

    public void setHobby(String h){
    hobby = h;
    }

    }
```

**Read from File and create Linked List Method:**

```
    LinkedList<LinkedAccountList> account = new LinkedList<LinkedAccountList>();

    try
    {
    read(account, "file.txt");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    display(account);
    }

    public static void read(LinkedList<LinkedAccountList> account, String inputFileName) throws java.io.IOException
    {
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
    while(infile.ready())
    {
    String username = infile.readLine();
    String password = infile.readLine();
    String email = infile.readLine();
    String name = infile.readLine();
    String breed = infile.readLine();
    String gender = infile.readLine();
    String age = infile.readLine();
    String state = infile.readLine();
    String hobby = infile.readLine();

    LinkedAccountList d = new LinkedAccountList(username, password, email, name, breed, gender, age, state, hobby);
    account.add(d);
    }
    infile.close();
    }
```

**Here is what the output looks like(Look closely and you can see the problem):**

```
Username: tobi
Password: tobi
Email: tobi@hotmail.com
Name: tobi
Breed: Mixed Breed
Gender: Male
Age: 3-4
State: Virginia
Hobby: Walking
Username: 
Password: lily
Email: lily
Name: lily@hotmail.com
Breed: lily
Gender: Yorkshire Terrier
Age: Female
State: 3-4
Hobby: Hawaii
Username: Jumping
Password:  peppy
Email: peppy
Name: peppy@hotmail.com
Breed: peppy
Gender: Chihuahua
Age: Male
State: 7-8
Hobby: Alaska
Username: Sleeping
Password: fluffy
Email: fluffy
Name: fluffy@hotmail.com
Breed: fluffy
Gender: Mixed Breed
Age: Female
State: 3-4
Hobby: Virginia
Username: Walking 
Password: flower
Email: flower
Name: flower@hotmail.com
Breed: flower
Gender: Chihuahua
Age: Female
State: 7-8
Hobby: Alaska
Username: Sleeping
Password: null
Email: null
Name: null
Breed: null
Gender: null
Age: null
State: null
Hobby: null
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but why is your class called `LinkedAccountList` instead of `Account`?

Comment: where is your display method?

Comment: I plan on changing it lol, but no reason

Comment: I have not built the display method yet, I am just using println to test it.

Comment: your toString add a new line and a space before the information,. i don't find something rare in the output,. or could you tell us what kind of output do you want it looks like,.?

Comment: basically I will create a display method that shows certain accounts in a text box. Each part of account data will display on a separate line with one line in-between each account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any validation, any logging.
You should at least create method:

```
public String readLine(BufferedReader br){
    String rl = br.readLine();
    if (rl.trim().length() > 2) {
        return rl;
    }else return readLine(br);
}
```

and use it like:

```
...
     while(infile.ready())
        {
          String username = readLine(infile); // instead of String username = infile.readLine();
```

Also using so long constructor argument is error-prone

> LinkedAccountList (String username, String password, String email,
>   String name, String breed, String gender, String age, String state,
>   String hobby){

Use ony `setX(String arg)` method. This is common practise in DAO pattern.

Comment: I added the method you put down and after the first account is read into the linked list another line is being added. How would I make it so that when it finds a blank line it just skips it instead and reads the next line?

Comment: Okay so basically I used your method. And I added the extra line to my readfile method thanks to Stephen C so its working now.

Comment: And now? - I have hanged the method. Any exceptions or sth?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. The problem seems to be that your `file.txt` has an extra newline between `Walking` and `lily`. Double-check the file and make sure there isn't one.

Comment: I don't have extra lines or spaces in my text file... It just doesnt show up properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously not on the output side.  A bug in toString() wouldn't cause it to produce output like that.

It looks like there is an extra empty line in the input after each record.  That's causing your `read` method to get out of step by one extra line each iteration of the loop.  If this is the problem, the fix is to add an extra readLine call to skip over the blank line.

---

On a separate note, your choice of class name is particularly poor.  The `LinkedAccountList` class does not represent a list of anything.  It represents a single account.

Comment: I am going to change the class name

Comment: Adding an extra line at the end of the while loop helped out but there is still a problem. Once it gets to the last two accounts its skipping the username of the second to last, and its skipping the password of the last.